# how to populate text area with database value before form load in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have used **hook_form_FORM_ID_alter( )** function to alter a menu_edit_menu form to add few fields. I ve stored the values from those fields in a table when submit action is performed. what I need now is when the particular form entry is loaded again for editing. The fields should be populated with the data in the database before form loads. Can anyone tell me how this could be done.

I have tried using **hook_validate ( )** function but the function is called when the submit action is performed which is of no use in this regard. I have to perform the database query before the form gets rendered to populate the text fields with data from tables. Kindly provide me some insight into how this could be accomplished.

I have a problem with the sql select query as well/

```
    $query = db_select('menu_custom');
$query
->fields(array('menu_name','role1','role2','role3'))
->condition('check',1,'=')
->conditon('title',$form_state['values']['title'])
->execute();

foreach($query as $record)
{
    $mname = $result ->menu_name;
    $rl1 = $result -> role1;
    $rl2 = $result -> role2;
    $rl3 = $result -> role3;
    dpm($mname."  ".$rl1);

}
```

I am getting error that my field specification is wrong but I cant figure out the problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit too long for a comment so I'll put it here:

The only error you've got in your query is that the first argument passed to the `fields()` function needs to be the name/alias of the table from which the fields are coming. So your query should probably look something like this:

```
$query = db_select('menu_custom')
  ->fields('menu_custom', array('menu_name','role1','role2','role3'))
  ->condition('check',1,'=')
  ->conditon('title',$form_state['values']['title'])
  ->execute();
```

Comment: I have one more question. how can i access the title before its is loaded. when i had to edit the form. the value of the title field is set as default and i need to get that value to use in the query. I ve tried to access it through $form_state['values']['title'] but it didn help. can you tell me how we could get that form data.

Comment: It depends really...where in the database are you saving the title when the form is submitted?

Comment: The title is stored is menu_custom table. When the previously added menu is edited from structure->menu option. The title should be extracted before the edit_menu_edit form is loaded and add the values of role1, role2 and role3 in their respective text fields.

Comment: the values will be in the $form when loaded.I tried to access the value through $form['title']['default_value'] but I cant retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1):

You get the data from your database in your form function, and put them as default_value

```
$name = db_query(YOUR_SQL);
$form['first_name'] = array(
  '#title' => t('First Name'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => $name,
);
```

is this what you meant?

Comment: I wanted to try your solution but I am getting problem with my SQL query.

Comment: @DrupalDeveloper Your query should be going through `db_query`, not `db_select`. I edited the answer to that effect

Comment: @Clive I have added the sql statement in the question. can you please tell me where I am going wrong.?

Comment: @Karel-Jan Misseghers Thank you very much. This helped me with my issue.